# See a hierarchical structure of issue/task for an epic/feature in Jira

Tags: configure, jira, report, app, jira-agile

I want to **see the complete structure of issues/tasks** of a parent and higher lever on **Jira (epic**, feature) and export to a format so i can process (spreadsheet, xml,..).

I can't see a report to print an Outline structure or a gantt style graph

On the other hand **I've no rights to install on the server**.
So, installing "structure" from "almworks" or similar solutions are not valid solutions and they have to be based on client side; user config for default Jira, webbrowser extensions, scrapping the webpage...